# How do I draw a straight line on plot using R?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I would like to draw a straight line on plot using the following linear equation.

```
y = 2.522x-1.331
```

I used the following code to get a scatterplot.

```
data=read.csv("C://book.csv")
plot(data$x,data$y)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use function `abline`:

```
abline(a=-1.331, b=2.522)
```

Argument `a` is the intercept and argument `b` the slope.
See `?abline` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use `abline`, e.g.

```
abline(-1.331, 2.522)
```